# Pass an array from stacknavigator as a prop to screen react native navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-navigation, prop

```
  state = {
    title: []
  }
  render() {
    return (<NavigationContainer>
<Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen
name="Dashboard"
component={Dashboard}
initialParams={{title:this.state.title}}
/>
</Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>}
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(prop) {
        super(prop);
        console.log(  this.props.route.params)
        this.state = {
            search:"",
templist:this.props.route.params.title,
            title: this.props.route.params.title}
```

**I want to pass the title(Array) in state to Screen
But I am not getting the array in screen **

Comment: Are you getting the params in the log you have put?

Comment: No! I am getting undefined value

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled into a similar problem. Made it work by stringifying the array I was trying to pass

`{title: JSON.stringify(this.state.title)}`